# dynamic variable assignment in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am very much new in shell scripting and just got the below mentioned export of variable in shell :

```
export VAR_FILE=${*: -1}
```

Can anyone help me to understand this ,as I am not able to understand this

Comment: A simpler way to get (specifically) the last argument is `${!#}`.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, let's grab [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) and go:

`export variable[=value]` - "Mark each name to be passed to child processes in the environment.". That means that if you run another process from this shell (ie. a subshell with a command: `sh -c 'echo $variable'`) it will share the variable value.

`$*` - "($*) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.". For example: `sh -c 'echo $1' -- 1`, `$1` will expand to the "first position argument". So `$*` expands to all positional parameters.

`${parameter:offset:length}` - This is named "substring expansion". It expands to characters starting at offset. If the paramter is `*` or `@` it exapnds to positional parameter, ie: `${*:2:1}` is equal to `$2`. You can also give negative offset, it then counts from the back. If you omit `:length` part, it assumes that length is infinite (to the end of string, to the last positional parameter).

`${*:-1}` - this will not work as you expect, cause `${parameter:-word}` expands to `1` if `$*` is null or unset. That means that we need a space between `:-` so bash does not confuse substring expansion with `:-`.

`${*: -1}` - this will give you the last positional parameter. ie. `sh -c 'echo ${*: -1}' -- 1 2 3` will output 3.

`export VAR_FILE=${*: -1}` - get's the last positional parameter, assigns it to VAR_FILE variable and set's that VAR_FILE variable will be exported to subprocesses.

Answer (score 2):

`$*` is a special variable which expands to the list of positional parameters (arguments to your script), separated by a space character.

`${list: -1}` expands to the last element of a list.

So this sets the environment variable `VAR_FILE` to the last argument passed to the script.

---

Note that for an array that you define yourself, the syntax would be different:

```
list=( a b 'c d' )
export foo=${list[*]: -1} # list[*] instead of just *
```

Comment: Actually, this is one of the few places where the `*` version works as well as `@` -- they're in contexts where word splitting and glob expansion don't occur, and there's only one argument (/element) being extracted means that `*`'s usual problem of mushing multiple arguments together doesn't apply.

Comment: @Gordon thanks - I decided to remove that part of my answer as it didn't really relate directly to the question and made things potentially more confusing.